# Destination Host Unreachable between two Raspberry PIs

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, network-interface

I have an ad-hoc IPv4 network with raspberry-pis. Right now these nodes are next to each other and whenever I try to ping from 10.0.0.4 to 10.0.0.6 this is the output.

```
PING 10.0.0.6 (10.0.0.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.4 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.4 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.4 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

the routes seem fine on both devices , these are their iwconfig, route, arp outputs :

On 10.0.0.4

```
pi@pi-raspberry4:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wdongle
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wboard
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wboard
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wdongle

pi@pi-raspberry4:~$ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.0.0.1                         (incomplete)                              wboard
192.168.1.7              ether   28:39:26:c6:2e:af   C                     wdongle
10.0.0.6                         (incomplete)                              wboard
10.0.0.2                         (incomplete)                              wboard
10.0.0.16                        (incomplete)                              wboard
192.168.1.254            ether   cc:7b:35:0d:7c:f8   C                     wdongle
10.0.0.15                        (incomplete)                              wboard
10.0.0.12                        (incomplete)                              wboard
pi@pi-raspberry4:~$ iwconfig
wdongle   IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"tplinktest"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 14:CC:20:64:C7:10   
          Bit Rate:300 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=98/100  Signal level=64/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

wboard    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"RPiAdHocNetwork"  
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Cell: 9A:29:92:92:6B:6C   
          Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=1 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
eth0      no wireless extensions.

ip6tnl0   no wireless extensions.
```

On 10.0.0.6

```
pi@pi-raspberry6:/etc$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wdongle
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     1002   0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wboard
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wboard
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wdongle


pi@pi-raspberry6:/etc$ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.0.0.2                 ether   b8:27:eb:c6:8b:41   C                     wboard
192.168.1.254            ether   cc:7b:35:0d:7c:f8   C                     wdongle
10.0.0.1                         (incomplete)                              wboard
10.0.0.15                        (incomplete)                              wboard
10.0.0.4                         (incomplete)                              wboard
192.168.1.7              ether   28:39:26:c6:2e:af   C                     wdongle

pi@pi-raspberry6:/etc$ iwconfig
wdongle   IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"tplinktest"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 14:CC:20:64:C7:10   
          Bit Rate:300 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=75/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

wboard    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"RPiAdHocNetwork"  
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Cell: 9A:29:92:92:6B:6C   
          Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=1 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
eth0      no wireless extensions.

ip6tnl0   no wireless extensions.
```

**My question:** what could be causing this and how can It be fixed? (unless its faulty hardware)

Note : My network is currently composed of 4 raspberry pis (one of which is 3B+ the rest 3B). Each one of them is in the ad-hoc network via the board NIC and in my home network via an external dongle. Nodes 10.0.0.4 -6 - 15 are running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and node 10.0.0.2 probably has the NOOBS distro for rpis ( i didn't find an lsb_release )

The only nodes that seem to be interacting with each other are 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.6. Previously I was running some iperf experiments and they have transmitted about 1 Gb of data each but suddenly some nodes disappeared and were not reachable (namely 10.0.0.4 and 10.0.0.15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was **sshguard**

I didn't know sshguard was running and made some failed attempts between the raspberries. In the failed login attempt logs there existed this line:

```
Blocking 192.168.1.7:4 for >630secs: 40 danger in 4 attacks over 2 seconds (all: 40d in 1 abuses over 2s)
```

sshguard seems to block all ipv4 traffic from suspected attackers and turns out I was the attacker